# Listing files in google cloud storage in python 2.7

Tags: python, filesystems, google-cloud-storage

I have a project in Google API Engine where I use Google Cloud Storage to save some files in one task and list some of this files in another task to process them. I couldn't find any answers here([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657549/get-list-of-files-in-google-cloud-storage-appengine-php) is in php, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866206/file-listing-from-google-cloud-storage) in java and neither were very helpful, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55636889/google-cloud-sdk-python-client-how-to-list-files-inside-of-a-cloud-storage-buck) seems to be python3)  or outside.
So What I want is something like this:

```py
import cloudstorage

files = cloudstorage.list('/bucket/foo/bar')
for file in files:
  # process files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exactly the path you want, you can use [listbucket](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions#listbucket) from cloudstorage. So to list all files in '/bucket/foo/bar' use:

```py
import cloudstorage

files = cloudstorage.listbucket('/bucket/foo/bar')
for file in files:
  file_name = file.filename
  # process file
```

Each file in the iterator returned from `listbucket` is [GCSFileStat](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/gcsfilestat_class) instance

You can also filter files by the beginning of the file name, for example, to list every file in the previous folder that begins with 'baz':

```
files = cloudstorage.listbucket('/bucket/foo/bar/baz')
```

Or list all the files after `test.json`:

```
files = cloudstorage.listbucket('/bucket/foo/bar/test.json')
```

To use these in unittest, you will need to setup the blobstore and urlfect stubs from testbed:

```py
import unittest
from google.appengine.ext import testbed

class CloudStorageTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        cls.testbed.activate()

        cls.testbed.init_blobstore_stub()
        cls.testbed.init_urlfetch_stub()
```

In my tests, you need both urlfetch and blobstore stubs to be able to use the cloud store in the tests. [Here](https://gist.github.com/franksands/65e5bcc56c56f678aa012281e1d5de22) is a gist with the whole test file